# Editing question with significant change, possibly affecting existing answers

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446151/three-dimensional-array-in-c-program) was [edited because](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446151/three-dimensional-array-in-c-program#comment44250536_26446151) it was from a question paper and was incorrectly quoted. However, the question already has several answers that all have used the information in the original question. The edit changes this information, specifically two of four alternatives for one "correct choice".

While I understand the editor's wish to quote the actual paper, thus making this question more useful if more people are interested in this specific question, edits like these can invalidate the existing answers, and therefor render the question and answers useless. I'm not saying this is the case for this particular edit, but should those kinds of edits be rolled back to the original intent of the question?

Answer (score 2):

Correcting **code** in a question is considered **a big no-no**. This can only make answers to the question obsolete and irrelevant. To cite from an "official guide", [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/1820286):

> Editing Code in Questions
>
> Code in questions should only be edited for formatting and readability. **Editing the syntax or correcting typos in code in questions can fix the problem that the person asking the question has, causing answers to be unable to address the problem**.

(emphasis mine).

As a relevant option for future questions there is a close reason for the particular case of a typo/syntax mistake:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

To get back to the question, the edit should be rolled back and that's what I will do right now.

Comment: That's what I thought, thank you :)

Comment: It's good you raised this issue. We now have one question fixed.

Comment: that supposes that *any* code-edit changes the meaning of the question though. That's not always the case, and code-edits removing distractions from the actual question do improve it. Though one must be tripple-sure, and if neccessary also adapt any answers. Also, take care the post you quoted is only a candidate for becoming faq...

Comment: @Deduplicator When editing I personally tend to remove irrelevant code in a well-structured questions that fail to contain minimal code (plain copypasted document), as removal of CSS styles within huge HTML code when the question doesn't concern styles at all or remove irrelevant code blocks/fuctions/other code clutter that repel people from answering a clear question. For sure, answer-dependent mistakes should be left alone and you've always got other tools at hand as closing/downvoting.